# Datatable with client side pagination in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I'm using `jQuery` `Datatable` in my application by default REST will sends only first 10 records along with that it adds `pageCount` if i add the page number to REST `URI` again it will sends next 10 records. 
Here my problem is once i got the first 10 records i want to draw the `datatable` at first shot and i want to add page number based on `pageCount` value in REST response. When user click on next page (say, 2) it has to make a Ajax call from `UI` and it has to redraw the table with next 10 records and previous 10 should be available.

Comment: So, you want the normal pagination behavior but you want it to cache the previously loaded pages to avoid unneeded server hits?

Answer (score 0):

If  what you want is to keep a cache of previously loaded pages, you could try the pipelining strategy outlined [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html).

Basically, it intercepts the ajax call so the table uses data from a cache pool if available, or performs the ajax call if not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, basically what i want is.

Comment: when i query on REST for the first time, it will returns the response in the following format:
`pageNum: 1
pageSize: 10
results: Array[10]
totalPages: 2
totalRecords: 20`

Now i would like to draw data table based on above response.
**result:** object contains response (first 10 records) now when user clicks on page number (say, 2) again i want to query on the same REST uri with query filter i.e. ?page=2 now i want to populate them in second page.